# Existence of a sequence of continuous functions convergent pointwise to the indicator function of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Prove that there does not exist a sequence of continuous functions $
f_n :\left[ {0,1} \right] \to R
$ such that converges pointwise, to the function 
$$f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $x$ is rational},\\\\
    1 & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}.
$$

I have no idea How can I prove this. Prove that there no exist such sequence if the convergence is uniform, it's easy, because the limit would be continuous, but here I don't know How can I do. I suppose that some "nice" properties are "preserved" in the limit, in this kind of convergence, but I don't know any of them.

Comment: I'm not voting to close, but this question is essentially a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/75192/

Comment: Ok, closed it , if you want, I did not see that post

Comment: Ok, closed it , if you want, I did not see that post, I think that you are exagerating, but I don´t know what it is measurable functions , and this kind of things :S

Comment: I said that I **didn't** vote to close and I meant it. Still, the point is that the set of discontinuity of a pointwise limit of continuous functions is a set of [first category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set), while your function is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: Wow! That´s nice!!!  where can I find a proof of this fact? Or at least the name of the theorem, to find it´s proof

Comment: It's a theorem of Baire. In his answer in the thread mentioned above LostInMath points to Theorem 1.19 on page 20 of Bruckner, Bruckner & Thomson *[Real analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=1WY6u0C_jEsC&pg=PA20)* (if you can't access that page, changing google.com to google.cl may help)

Comment: Jeeze. how can cambridge set something like this for an analysis II question...

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541619/proof-that-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-f-n-cannot-converge-pointwise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointwise limit of continuous functions is 1) measurable and 2) pointwise discontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75192/pointwise-limit-of-continuous-functions-is-1-measurable-and-2-pointwise-discon)

Answer (score 8):

The reason (given in comments) that $f$ is not a pointwise limit of continuous functions is that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, while pointwise limits of continuous functions have a comeager set of points of continuity. The latter fact is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/381546/79365), additional details are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75218/79365), and a textbook reference is: [Theorem 1.19 on page 20](https://books.google.com/books?id=yqK38V80_skC&pg=PA18) of *Real analysis* by Bruckner, Bruckner & Thomson.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to this old posting.

Suppose $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ is such that
$f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ pointwise. Define the sets
$$E_n:=\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|f_m(x)|\leq\frac12\}$$
Each $E_n$, being the intersection of closed sets, is closed.

If $x\in E_n$, then $|f_m(x)|\leq\frac12$ for all $m\geq n$ and so, $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)=\lim_nf_n(x)\leq\frac12<1$, each means that $x$ is irrational. Hence $E_n$ is a nowhere dense closed set.

Conversely,  $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\subset \bigcup_nE_n$ since for each irrational $x$, $f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.
Hence
$$\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_nE_n$$
and so, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is a set of first category.
This implies that $\mathbb{R}=\big(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\big)\cup\mathbb{Q}$ is of first category. We know from Baire's theorem that $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) is of second category: contradiction!