# function for which I cannot have a sequence of $C^{\infty}$-functions that converges everywhere pointwise to it.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. I know I cannot find a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions that converges uniformly to $f$ in general. I also know that I can find a sequence of sequence of $C^\infty$ functions that converge to $f$ in $L^p$. I know that I can find a subsequence of the latter that converges a.e. to $f$. But what about a convergence everywhere? What would be an example of a function where I cannot have convergence in every point by a sequence of $C^{\infty}$-functions? Maybe $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (characteristic function on the rationals)? How could I prove this (the result with $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}$)? Is there something more simple?

Comment: This has been studied by Baire and has nothing to do with $L^p$ spaces. Search for "Baire one functions". If you read French, as your username suggests, you will have access to a lot more material.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at the concept

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1799537/8157) could be useful.