# Issue with pointwise limit to the indicator function on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

As discussed in the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541619/proof-that-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-f-n-cannot-converge-pointwise/1444407) it's impossible to have a pointwise limit of continuous functions converge to $1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$.

That said, why doesn't the following sequence of functions converge to $1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$?

Let $S = \{q_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ be an $\mathbb{N}$-indexed sequence of rationals in $[0,1]$.

$f^{(1)}(x) = 1 - \left((x-q_1)\right)^{(1/1)}$

$f^{(2)}(x) = 1 - \left((x-q_1)(x-q_2)\right)^{(1/4)}$

$f^{(3)}(x) = 1 - \left((x-q_1)(x-q_2)(x-q_3)\right)^{(1/9)}$

In General:

$f^{(i)}(x) = 1 - \left(\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(x-q_j)\right)^{\frac{1}{i^2}}$

If the power $\frac{1}{i^2}$ isn't small enough, then just assume that it's some sufficiently small value like $\frac{1}{e^i}$. The idea is that when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(x) = 1$, since the term $(x-q)$ will be in the product, and when $x$ is irrational, the $i^2$ root will have the product approach 1.

Comment: I assume you want absolute values inside the product -- you probably don't want to be taking roots of negative numbers.

Comment: Do you want $\prod_{j=1}^i$ instead of $\prod_{j=1}^\infty$ in the definition of $f^{(i)}$?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you can choose a power small enough. For each $x$, you can find a subsequence of $\{q_j\}$ such that $|x-q_{j_k}|<\varepsilon$ for any given $\varepsilon>0$; you have to argue that you can find a power small enough to counteract the effect of multiplying so many $\varepsilon$s in.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be said about limit of $a_n^{b_n}$ if $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to \infty$ or $a_n \to 0$ $b_n \to 0$. $f(x)$ is not well defined for $x$ irrational.