# Exists continuous $f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that converges pointwise, as $n \to \infty$, to $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

Does there exist a sequence of continuous $f_n: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that converges pointwise, as $n \to \infty$, to $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$, the characteristic function of the rationals in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77307/existence-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-pointwise-convergence

Comment: The general idea that should come to mind is this: suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions converging pointwise to a function $f$.  If each $f_n$ has "Property X" does that imply anything at all about what property that $f$ should have?  That way you can spare yourself the grief perhaps of having to construct an example of a sequence of Property X functions converging to some proposed example.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be such a sequence.
$\chi_{\Bbb Q}$ *is* a double limit of continuous functions, cf. [the Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function). Thus, it's a Baire class 2 function. As the article states, it can't be a Baire class 1 function (single pointwise limit of continuous functions) because such functions have a meager set of discontinuities, unlike $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$. For a proof, see the links and reference in the stackexchange Q&A which Joey Zou cites in his comment.

Comment: If  $f$  is a pointwise limit of continuous real functions then $f^{-1}\{y\}=\{x :f(x)=y\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set for every $y$. A corollary to the Baire Category Theorem is that a dense $G_{\delta}$ set of reals is uncountable.